# Getting $$ to hold the concatenation of $1 & $2

Tags: c, yacc

I need to combine phrases together as a sentence and pass that as words.
I have a yacc rule which states:

```
words : words WORD  {
                if($1 == NULL)
                {
                    $$ = $2;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\t$1 = %s\n",$1);
                    printf("\t$2 = %s\n",$2);
                    strBuffer[0]='\0';
                    strcat((char *)strBuffer,$1);
                    $$ = strcat((char *)strBuffer,$2);
                    printf("\t$$ = %s\n\n",$$);                             
                }
            }
```

char strBuffer[200] is a sufficiently large global array.

But when I run the parser, I get:

```
$1 = The G
$2 = nats and 
$$ = nats and
```

What should I do so that both $1 & $2 make it into $$?

Comment: And I thought this question was about getting money :(

Comment: Sorry for the let down, guess I should've been more verbose. Please continue your search at http://www.worldlottery.net/ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sprintf($$, "%s%s", $1, $2);
```

Comment: Alright, that works. But can I be sure that sufficient space is allocated for $$ to prevent any overflows?

Comment: You can use `snprintf` to prevent overflows (AFAIK there is a `define`'d size for `$$` array somewhere in the yacc headers). Another (dirty) wat is to manually call `realloc` on `$$`. AFAIK, `$$` well be freed by yacc in the end.